# How to correctly install/use RPi Pico SDK for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi-pico

I installed the 'starter pack' using the [Windows Pico Installer](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-pico-windows-installer/) but VS Code gives me red error squiggles wehn i open any example files. When i red about this problem, i got one solution that said i must add `${env:PICO_SDK_PATH}/**` to the include path setting of C/C++ configuration in VS Code but it was already there and i got two more error messages there what you can see in the photos.

The installer seemed fine but i guess it wasn't, how can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

**EDIT: I think i figured it out, i uninstalled everything and now i install every tool step-by-step by hand. Only thing i need to figure out now is how to create a shortcut (or icon) for VS Code to launch from a specified directory (that contains pico-sdk) and using VS Code Developer Command Prompt. Can y'all help?**

Comment: `export` the environment variables from your `.bashrc` so the environment is that of the parent-shell. Your distro may export them through `/etc/profile.d/` system wide. Either way is fine. For example, I have the SDK, examples, extra, playground and FreeRTOS-Kernel installed in `/opt`, adjust he path as needed. Then `PICO_SDK_PATH="/opt/pico-sdk"` and `export PICO_SDK_PATH`, the same for `PICO_EXAMPLES_PATH="/opt/pico-examples"`, `PICO_EXTRAS_PATH="/opt/pico-extras"`, `PICO_PLAYGROUND_PATH="/opt/pico-playground"` and `FREERTOS_KERNEL_PATH="/opt/FreeRTOS-Kernel"`. It will work then.

Comment: On Windows you can add directly to your Environment Variables, Start-Menu, type "Environmen" and choose to Add to the environment. You must close and restart any apps that make use of the environment so the changes are seen.

Comment: I think i figured it out, i uninstalled everything and now i install every tool step-by-step by hand. Only thing i need to figure out now is how to create a shortcut (or icon) for VS Code to launch from a specified directory (that contains pico-sdk) and using VS Code Developer Command Prompt. Can y'all help?

Comment: The VS Code (or VS Developers Command Prompt) is a shortcut that is found several directories down in Either the Program Files/VS... or Program Data/VS... I can't recall which. Find the shortcut (possibly even the one in `\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs...` and right-click and choose Properties. There is a Start-in directory edit box you can use to set the directory. You can also edit the environment setup files directly (search `"Set startup directory in VS Developers Command Prompt"` and that should get you the MS page that explains it.